# Как сделать каталог товаров?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Есть приложение для  `ios`, которое называется Яндекс Маркет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать такой же каталог товаров, где есть картинка, цена и название, которые берутся с определенного сайта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну возьмитесь же вы последовательно изучать Objective-C  и iOS SDK!  Большинство ваших вопросов элементарны. И этот также элементарен. В самом простом случае создается таблица, каждый ряд которой представляет собой единицу товара. Выводите в ячейку всю нужную вам информацию. Предварительно скачиваете нужную информацию с сайта посредством веб-запроса. Соответственно у такого приложения должна быть серверная часть.